# creating custom image in azure fails

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-storage

I'm new to azure cloud. I'm trying to upload my application vhd file in azure storage cloud and wanted to create an image out of it, so that I could launch a vm. I was able to upload file to storage and while trying to create an image it fails with InvalidParameter.

Comment: Screenshot of the command and error will help greatly.

Comment: I'm trying to upload the vhd file manually in UI and then tried creating image which is failing with InvalidParameter.

Comment: The error should state the invalid parameter.  Just the word invalid parameter is too vague for anyone to know what the issue is.

Comment: Any more question? Or if the answer is helpful you can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a managed image from the VHD file that you upload to Azure Storage. Follow the steps in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/create-vm-specialized#option-2-upload-a-specialized-vhd), it references the PowerShell command. If you need more help please let me know.